# Tidy doesn't fix indentation of <option> and </select> tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, tidy

I enter the following in the HTML box of a stack snippet:

```html
<div>
          <select>
              <option></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
```

Then I click `Tidy`, and the result is:

```html
<div>
  <select>
              <option></option>
                  </select>
</div>
```

It fixed the indentation of `<select>` and `</div>`, but `<option></option>` and `</select>` are not correct.

Comment: OK, that's <select><option>hilarious</option><option>intriguing</option></select>.

Comment: You just have to adjust your definition of *tidy* ...

Comment: I wanted to compare this to the behavior over at JSFiddle but couldn't get that to actually tidy anything.

Comment: @BSMP I just tried it there, it did exactly the same thing as Stack Snippet. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ekooxtt4/

Comment: It appears that StackOverflow uses [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) for the CSS/JS/HTML formatting in the editor. By default, that library [explicitly excludes `<select>`](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/blob/ab785ee87d42c8c6aa09eb971916bfeee1c26f81/js/src/html/beautifier.js#L93) from the list of elements that get formatted. The good news is that list is configurable.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: Heh... funny that it excludes select because it's phrasing content - that's exactly how I used it in my comment above. Inline, as part of a sentence. Running my comment through tidy now will *break* that sentence by isolating and indenting the select, resulting in a space between it and the punctuation mark. Having said that, I recognize that far fewer people use select elements inline than as blocks, so it's on me to be careful never to run all my markup through tidy...

Comment: @BoltClock I guess it's for some kind of Mad Libs use of select?

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected. It looks like tidy preserves the lack of spacing between the end tag and any non-whitespace characters after all.

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Exactly as Cᴏʀʏ pointed out, the formatter was explicitly excluding `<select>` tags.