# `this` variable prints weirdly when using JS snippets

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-snippets

Inspired from a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378563/3029173) I noticed that the snippets code console.logs `this` weirdly in the following scenario:

```js
function hello() {
  console.log('hello this is', this);
}

hello.call(5);
```

which prints `hello this is {}`

In node, this returns: `hello this is [Number: 5]`

and in chrome, this prints: `hello this is Number {5}`

What gives?

Comment: This is sorta fixed in a update to the stack snippet console, that was written for [this bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361306/stack-snippets-logging-nested-objects-weirdly). Sadly, updating the snippet library seems to be low priority.

Comment: what is the desired/ expected output?

Comment: Do node and chrome have the exact same version of the exact same javascript engine?

Comment: @Ilene anything more useful than `{}`. I would prefer `[Number: 5]` given that Objects are printed with [] in JS

Comment: You could always use `console.log('hello this is', this.toString())` or `console.log(```hello this is ${this}```)` instead of `this`; then you'll get the default `toString` implementation (in this case, `hello this is 5`). But as @Cerbrus notes, the Stack Snippets code base hasn't been changed since... 2014? No, looks like they at least [updated the Tidy code in April](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366272/215552). Maybe they can roll in the latest from canon...